# Check if user has access to a webpage or not?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to check if the current user has access to a webpage or not using JavaScript or Jquery. I have tried below code which is working fine in Firefox and Chrome. But Its not working in IE.:

```js
var request;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  request = new XMLHttpRequest();
else
  request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  
request.open('GET', "--some url--", false);
request.send();
console.log(request);

if (request.responseURL.indexOf("AccessDenied.aspx") > -1) {
  //do something;
}
```

In my case i need `request.responseURL`. Which i am getting in chrome and Firefox. But in IE I don't get this property of `request`.

Comment: Which version of IE? `XMLHttpRequest` is supported down to IE7. Also, please check the console and edit the question to include any errors you receive

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Its IE11...

Comment: In which case this should work fine. Please check for errors in the console.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I have updated the question...Please check.

Comment: You need to check that property after the request has completed: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/responseURL.

Comment: That's what my concern is. IE doesn't support this property. Is there any other way so that i can check if user has access to a webpage or not(for all the browsers.).